# C thread-mutex codes errors?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Here is the code:

```
....
typedef struct {
  int buf[10];
  long head, tail;
  int full, empty;
  pthread_mutex_t *mut;
  pthread_cond_t *notFull, *notEmpty;
} queue;

int main(){
  queue *que;
  pthread_t sup, cut;
  que = queueInit();
  if(que == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Queue Init failed");
    exit(1);
  }
  pthread_create(&sup, NULL, insertQueue, (void*) que);
  pthread_create(&cut, NULL, insertQueue, (void*) que);
  pthread_join(sup,NULL);
  pthread_join(cut,NULL);
  queueDelete(que);
  return 0;
}

void *insertQueue(void *q)
{
  queue *que;
  int i;
  que = (queue *)q;
  for(i=0; i<20;i++){
    // Get mutex lock on the queue
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut); // Question (i) I guess this line is wrong
    while(que>full){
      printf("Its full");
      // pthread wait condition for queue not full
      pthread_cond_wait(&notFull, &mut); // Question (ii)
    }
    queueAdd(que,i);
    // Unlock the queue
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut); // Question (iii)
    // Send signal saying there is data to be read
    pthread_cond_signal(&notEmpty); // Question (iv)
    usleeep(100000);)
    return(NULL);
  }
}

queue *queueInit(void){
  queue *q;
  q = (queue *)malloc(sizeof(queue));
  if(q==NULL) return (NULL);
  q->empty = 1;
  q->full = 0;
  q->head = 0;
  q->tail = 0;
  q->mut=(pthread_mutex_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
  // Set default condition
  pthread_mutex_init(&mut,NULL); // Question v
  // Condition for not null
  pthread_mutex_init(&notNull,NULL); // Question vi
  // Condition for not empty
  pthread_mutex_init(&notEmpty,NULL); // Question vi
  return (q);
}
....
```

I have put my question in the code, i.e question i - vi

My feeling telling me, my arguments are wrong, for example the question vi:

```
pthread_cond_init(notEmpty,NULL);
```

it should be something else, not "(&notEmpty,Null)".

Please help.

Comment: Two condition variables looks ugly and that usually means it is not an ideal solution. You could just have a single condition variable "queueChanged" or something and flag that when the queue either gains or loses an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use `&` when you already have a pointer. Change this:

```
// Set default condition
  pthread_mutex_init(&mut,NULL); // Question v
  // Condition for not null
  pthread_mutex_init(&notNull,NULL); // Question vi
  // Condition for not empty
  pthread_mutex_init(&notEmpty,NULL); // Question vi
```

to this:

```
// Set default condition
  pthread_mutex_init(mut,NULL); // Question v
  // Condition for not null
  pthread_mutex_init(notNull,NULL); // Question vi
  // Condition for not empty
  pthread_mutex_init(notEmpty,NULL); // Question vi
```

Pay attention to `&` I have put away. `mut` is already a pointer, and making `&mut` is an attempt to get pointer to pointer to `pthread_mutex_t`

Comment: Thanks. How about the question i - iv? Any idea?

Comment: you should remove '&' there also. In all places.

Answer (score 2):

`notNull` is written as `notFull` in two places.
`notNull` and `notEmpty` are condition variables not mutexes and should be initialised as such.
No memory is allocated for `notNull` and `notEmpty`.

It may be better to declare `queue` as:

```
typedef struct {
  int buf[10];
  long head, tail;
  int full, empty;
  pthread_mutex_t mut;
  pthread_cond_t notFull;
  pthread_cond_t notEmpty;
} queue;
```

And then keep all the `&` characters. This means you can malloc the whole lot with a single call.

Lastly I think you mean `while(que->full)` not `while(que>full)`.